# Puppet client error when using puppet agent -t

Tags: puppet

I m trying to use puppet to manage my servers.

I m using opensource puppet

Actually, I have downloaded a module 'docker' (from garther/docker) and I have it in my module list in my master agent :

```
/home/skahrz/.puppet/modules
├── garethr-docker (v4.1.1)
├── puppetlabs-apt (v2.2.0)
├── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.9.0)
└── stahnma-epel (v1.1.1)
```

I have the following site.pp (I m actually learning step by step, not using environnements for the moment) :

```
node 'my.host.com' {

include 'docker'

docker::image { 'hello-world':
image_tag => 'precise',
}


}
```

When I try to use puppet agent -t on my client node, I got this error output :

```
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find class docker for my.host.com on node my.host.com
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

So, I tried to follow this link :

https://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/console_accessing.html

I can telnet my master from nodes.

But I dont have the console since I use the opensource ... So I m a bit locked.

Can anybody help me with this error ?

Comment: Is the master running from root (e.g. via passenger) or have you started as using `puppet master` as user `skahrz`? I notice that your modules are installed in `~/.puppet`. That is fine, but a root level master will not find them there.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your reply concerning ~/.puppet . I'll modify this. The master is running under skahrz yes

Comment: Does `puppet apply -e 'include docker' --noop` work on the command line of the master machine as user `skahrz` ? If not, investigate using `puppet apply --configprint modulepath`. If it does work, you will want to verify against `puppet master --configprint modulepath`. In case this does not yield any clues, stop the master process and restart using `puppet master --debug --verbose --no-daemonize` and watch the output as the agent checks in once more.

Comment: Okay, the first command failed. So I tried the second one : puppet apply --configprint /home/skahrz/.puppet/modules/docker/    and the output is : invalid parameter: /home/skahrz/.puppet/modules/docker/
. Weird ... I tried to run the last command (no-daemonize) and it displays that 'Error: Could not find class docker for my.host.com on node my.host.com' inside of the resultset

Comment: Please run the command verbatim: `--configprint modulepath`. You substituted the expected result there, which cannot work.

Comment: Sorry about that. The actual result is : /etc/puppet/modules:/usr/share/puppet/modules

Comment: That's the problem right there. Puppet tries the modules from `/etc/puppet`. Are you running as root after all? This is all quite inconsistent. If you can't make sense of it at all, then please make a pastebin with the output of `puppet master --configprint all` and link it to your question.

Comment: If you managed to resolve this by yourself, please add an answer to your own question. Thanks!